# problem in strtok function

Tags: c, linux

hi every one  i have an array

21 44 56 777

i am using strtok function to seperate them on the basis of space

```
int i;
char *token;
token = strtok(payload1, " ");
printf ( "\n\n\nTOKEN  %s" , token);
```

i works fine that is it displayed 21.
now i want display 44 using the same variable token how to do that

thanks kindly help me

Comment: `man strtok`. It even has an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to repeatedly apply strtok.

```
token = strtok(payload1, " "); 
while ( token != NULL)
    {
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    // do your stuffs
    }
```

Comment: sir please tell me that inside while you have written       strtok(NULL ," "). why we have to write null here here does array go  thank u

Comment: You can look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/, for detailed understanding.

Comment: I can add, that function strtok is stateful and "remeber" current string and position within it. A call with NULL tells the function, to search forward on the same string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while(token != NULL){
   token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: sir please tell me that inside while you have written       strtok(NULL ," "). why we have to write null here here does array go  thank u

Answer (score 0):

the implementation of strtok saves the pointer to the string in a private variable on the first call. On subsequent calls that the first parameter is NULL it will return the next token of initial string.

Since strtok uses some private storage to save the pointer you can not process two different strings simultaneously, and it is not reentrant.

If you want to sue strtok use the reentrant version, strtok_r that is safer even if you are not running multiple treads.

for example if function A is using strtok to parse a string and in the middle of it calls another function that also uses strtok to parse another string, function A will get the wrong result.

Also keep in mind that strtok modifies the string, ergo cannot be used on static allocations.